# Cant find "Read Lockout Time" and "Write Lockout Time" for delegation on OU

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003-r2, delegation, organizational-unit

Trying to delegate permissions to a group on a OU; but cant find  2 properties in special permissions for "User Objects" they are  "Read Lockout Time" and "Write Lockout Time" any reason i couldnt see them? I am using ADUC tool on a windows 7 machine with domain consisting of both windows 2003 R2 and Windows 2008 R2 domain controllers and i am a domain admin.

Comment: Are you looking at Property-specific permissions?

Comment: Did my answer actually fix your issue, or did @joeqwerty's comment above point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually %windir%\System32\dssec.dat to allow you to see these in ADUC on the computer you are using to create the delegations?  If you haven't changed the values from 7 to 0 then it won't show up in the GUI.

See here for details: http://www.expta.com/2008/09/how-to-delegate-right-to-unlock-user.html

[image]

Comment: Interesting info, but I've never had to do that and I can see both attributes. ?

Comment: @joeqwerty - I believe it is specific to the machine you are on.  A 2008 machine doesn't even have this attribute listed in dssec.dat and you are right you can see it in the GUI of a 2008 server.  I wonder if the OP's 7 machine he was trying this from didn't have it set right in dssec.dat?  That was the only thing I could think of when he said he couldn't see it.  I wonder if your comment is the right answer and he simply accepted mine?  I'll post a comment and see, happy to delete my answer if your comment led him to making sure he checked the box.

Comment: It couldnt see it when i did a Right click on OU and went to properties and security tab and looked at the permissions;  but i found it when i used "Delegate Control " option when right clicking the OU and navigating to user objects properties. I didnt need to make any changes on the dssec.dat file.